# Meaning of "unsatisfied claim upon his justice"

Tags: meaning, charles-dickens, little-dorrit

This is from Charles Dickens' *Little Dorrit*, Chapter 16:

> As often as he began to consider how to increase this inheritance, or to lay it by, so often his misgiving that there was some one with an **unsatisfied claim upon his justice**, returned;

What does "unsatisfied claim upon his justice" mean in the above passage?

Answer (score 1):

Arthur Clennam knows that there is a mystery in his background. He cannot help feeling that perhaps someone else is the rightful inheritor of his father's money. Such a person would have a **claim upon his justice**, i.e., could appeal to Arthur's sense of fairness / right and wrong. Until Arthur shares or relinquishes his inheritance, that person's claim would be **unsatisfied**.